# Why does timeit results in almost constant time for all memoization runs?

Tags: python, performance, dynamic-programming, memoization

We compute the Fibonacci number:

```py
def fibo_memo(i, memo={}):
    if i <= 0:
        return 0
    elif i == 1:
        return 1
    elif i in memo:
        return memo[i]
    else:
        memo[i] = fibo_memo(i-2, memo) + fibo_memo(i-1, memo)
        return memo[i]

def fibo_dp(i):
    if i <= 0:
        return 0
    elif i == 1:
        return 1

    dp = [0] * (i + 1)
    dp[1] = 1

    for j in range(2, i + 1):
        dp[j] = dp[j-1] + dp[j-2]

    return dp[i]

assert(fibo_memo(100) == fibo_dp(100))
```

Now time it:

```
i = 10
%timeit fibo_memo(i)  # 73 ns
%timeit fibo_dp(i)  # 309 ns

i = 100
%timeit fibo_memo(i)  # 73 ns
%timeit fibo_dp(i)  # 2.54 micro seconds

i = 1000
%timeit fibo_memo(i)  # 73 ns
%timeit fibo_dp(i)  # 33 micro seconds
```

Why does memoization result in almost constant time, unlike dynamic programming?

Comment: Does the `memo` persist between iterations within `%timeit` ?

Comment: @MichaelButscher that is a typo, it should be `fibo_memo`. Fixed.

Comment: The value of `memo` persists across *all* calls. I suspect you had already filled it with the values up to 100 before running your timing test.

Comment: Replace the mutable default with `None` and put `if memo is None: memo = {}` inside the function, and try timing it again.

Comment: Now, if you want to know how to do a "fair" timeit test that resets the memoized values before every run... I can write that when I get back to a computer if the question isn't already adequately answered by then.

Comment: @chepner Yes, that's right. Reset `memo` for new call, now it behaves correctly in `%timeit`.

Comment: @slothrop or chepner please write an answer if you would like to, I will accept it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This bug is more subtle than you think. Someone can guess that `memo` must persist across calls because `timeit` results are constant, but why? Why is `memo` not reseted, where does its value come from, which scope can access it and through which mechanism? One need to understand the details of mutable, reference, memory allocation, function init to answer these questions and get to a safe implementation.

Comment: @THN, the answer describes *exactly* what I thought the bug was; there are no subtleties I was not already aware of. Anyone who's been doing Python for any significant amount of time knows exactly how mutable default arguments work; it's a constant surprise for newcomers, but people don't stay newcomers.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sometimes people are blinded by their habits, and not think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mutable default argument of `fibo_memo`, which holds the memoized values, persists between iterations of `%timeit`. So all but the first iteration complete near-instantly. (And in fact, for `i = 10` and `i = 100`, the first iteration is probably near-instant too, since the `assert` check populated the memoization dict up to 100.)

For a like-for-like comparison, `fibo_memo` should be called with an empty memoization dict each time:

```
i = 10
%timeit fibo_memo(i, {})
%timeit fibo_dp(i)

i = 100
%timeit fibo_memo(i, {})
%timeit fibo_dp(i)

i = 1000
%timeit fibo_memo(i, {})
%timeit fibo_dp(i)
```

In my quick run on Google Colab, this shows very similar scaling behaviour for both solutions (roughly the expected `O(N)`, with the memoization solution taking about 3 times as long as the DP for each value of `i`).

Comment: Thanks, it's all clear now. I would have noticed it right away too if not after an all-nighter.